# Scientific Author Ranking Services

Tags: ranking

In the Economics profession, there is a free service called RePEc:

https://ideas.repec.org/

This service, amongst other things, ranks the top 5% of registered authors over a number of metrics (their publication number, citation, impact factor etc).

I'm wondering whether other fields (e.g., biology, physics) have a similar service which ranks top contributors to their fields.

Many thanks.

Comment: One might better wonder if any of those metrics actually provide useful information. That is your first question to answer.

Comment: It's always the same with bibliographic metrics, those who do not rank high or already have tenure find them to be not correct or not useful.

Comment: @CapeCode: I do not rank highly in, say, overall citations, and yet I'd argue my citation counts are generally *too high*, because they include throwaway references (of the kind "Furthermore, others used method X [citation], which is unrelated to our work."), as well as (e.g. in Google Scholar) citations by works such as student theses that obey to different "natural limits" than peer-reviewed papers.

Comment: _those who do not rank high or already have tenure find them to be not correct or not useful._ — Also those who do rank high, those who do not have tenure, and those who actually bother to look at where the data comes from.  If your accusation held any water, these metrics would pretty quickly fall out of favor, since only people who already have tenure serve on tenure committees.

Comment: To take "ownership" of your own question so you can edit it and post comments, register an account and follow [these instructions](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 2):

Thomson Reuters does that for all fields: http://highlycited.com/.

Comment: Where "all fields" means "All fields whose publications are reliably indexed by Thompson Reuters", which means not computer science.

Comment: They produce *some sort of ranking* for all academic fields, including CS. Whether these rankings are accurate, or meaningful, is another issue...